# Django monitor DataBase and Email as alert, if DB had reach an conditions

Tags: django, database, email, alert

I apologies if I'm asking something stupid.

Need some advice on design factor;

I had this Django Apps ready and now I want add in available to monitor DB, to compare and check on condition I require, and send email if condition is fit in requirement. Example:

```
(DB use space = 80%) => (limit DB use space = 70%)
send email to alert user
```

and I do not wish to open the webapp to be able send the email to user.

I'm using
Django 2.1
postgreSQL 9
and cloud server AWS

Now summarize my question will I be do this on django, or I had to do on DB side? and do point me some link or codes where I could start working this.

Applicate the help and really exited to hear the answer.

Comment: since you are using AWS, you can use aws rds if using a relational database.AWS provides a lot of tools to monitor the same